# Microsoft Sync Framework Not Syncing Non Clustered Indexes from SQL Server to SQL CE DB

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework

We're having an issue when using the Microsoft Sync Framework to sync tables and data from a centralized server down to local clients to enable local processing of that data and re-uploading/syncing of changes.

We can get the tables to sync from the server, creating the table(s) on the local client and filling it with data, however only the primary key is getting automatically created as a index on the local clients.  Performance is key and without the indexes some queries are receiving poor response times (e.g. 194 seconds vs. < 3 seconds).

Is there something we need to be sure to do to allow all indexes to be copied from theserver to the client by the framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design, sadly. You will have to run "CREATE INDEX" statements on your tables after initial sync.